# Excel Define Custom Numbering Formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to map integers to Ease-of-Use Values within Excel. There's a reason behind this as to why I can't just display the Value within the cell, so I'm hoping someone can guide me here.

**Background:**

---

I have a conditional formula to look at multiple conditions. There are one of four outcomes in this evaluation:
`1, 0, -1, -2`

The formula is:

`=IF([@Status]="RETENTION-HOLD", -2, IF([@Status]="UTILITY", -3, IF(AND(OR([@[User Contact?]]="Yes", [@[User Contact?]]="SMS'ed / Yes"), [@[2SV Activated?]]="Yes"), 1, IF(NOT([@Status]="Active"), 0, -1))))`

Each one represents an ease-of-use (EOU) value:

- 1 = Secure
- 0 = Partial
- -1 = Unsecure
- -2 = Other

The EOU Integers are required for Conditional Formatting on Icons, as the icons are number-conditioned, instead of text-conditioned like the colouring of cell conditions, etc.

**What I've Tried:**

---

I've customised my IF formulas to kick-out the evaluation values (ie. 1, 0, ...). Then, I used Custom Numbering on the results in the String: `"Secure";"Partial";"Unsecure";"Other"`

Using this, it only references the 1,0,-1 values which are correctly masked, and ignores the -2 placeholder.

**Required Outcome:**

---

I'd like to have a method, without the use of VBA or VLOOKUPS, to present me with more EOU value masks over the evaluation values, instead of only three options, so that I can do Custom Formatting and Special Rules with the eval-code, as well as the masked text.

I've figured that the Custom Numbering by default works by checking `POSITIVE`, `NEGATIVE`, and `ZERO` values. I'm pretty sure there must be another way to do this, to add more values.

**UPDATE**

- Added Formula

Comment: "I have a conditional formula to look at multiple conditions." -- Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1462729/edit) to include that formula?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've added the formula as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

Use a custom format for the first 3 outcomes:

```
"Secure";"Unsecure";"Partial"
```

[image]

Then use a Conditional Format rule to change the format when less than one:

The formula:

```
=A1<-1
```

The number format rule:

```
;"Other";
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @scott-craner, this works well for multiple other options to be added and formatted!